# Notable differense in the same pics while viewing in the Visual Studio designer and in the Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

While working with a picture, I noticed that the picture looks differently at the Blend and at Visual Studio Designer.
Of course I saved everything and both have exactly the same XAML code.

As an example (not worst case there). It is seen, here, that position of the lines looks differently.
Has anyone ever faced with such sort of phenomenon?

[from Blend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDrOM.png)

[VS2015 designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKHu.png)

Comment: The very short answer to this question is NO! You have to be more specific, perhaps show your XAML. Looking at your example I even doubt it is a picture.

Comment: That cannot be just a picture. Blend isn't going to move some bits of a bitmap round and make a totally different shape.

Comment: Just create a XAML, e.g. User Control. Open it in the Blend. Create couple of lines and join their ends. Then save it in the Blend and turn to VS Designer. The VS Designer will offer to reload everything. Press "All" and just compare both. You'll see significant difference between pics. Then compare both XAMLs. It doesn't look like rounding. It looks like significant issue.